# HTML <input type="file"> : Selecting file using double click, mouseUp event gets triggered for below controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("div").mouseup(function(){
        $(this).after("<p style='color:green;'>Mouse button released.</p>");
    });
    
    $("div").mousedown(function(){
        $(this).after("<p style='color:purple;'>Mouse button pressed down.</p>");
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: powderblue;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div style="border:1px solid red">Press down and release the mouse button over this div element.</div>
<input type="file"/>

</body>
</html>
```

**Hi,
I am using < input type="file" > in my code for selecting files. When I opens the file upload dialog and selects the file using double click then if that file upload dialog is covering (overlapping) by below div control for example  then mouseUp event gets triggered for my div element.**

Now open the file upload/selection dialog and select the file using double click, but place your dialog in such a position that your div element get covered (over-lapping each other) and double click selection of file should have div element under it.

You will see that mouseup event got fired as soon as you selects the file using double click in file upload window. double click event gets passed to underneath div element. Is it known issue of input type file? How to protect/avoid it? Any Solution?

Comment: I've got the same issue right now using firefox...

Comment: @Dubrzr Yeh now its reproducible on firefox but not on Chrome browser.

Comment: any solutions on this?

Answer (score -1):

Something wrong with your logic. If you try the run snippet here it actually allows you to double click a file *after* you clicked the input field unless you want it to launch after clicking the div in which case then jquery should call the input field with a click.

Comment: Hi Samuel, My issue is after double click on file in file upload window, my mouseUp event gets fired from div element. When my file upload/selection window is covering my div and file's double click haapened.

Comment: I don't get the same issue, what browser(s) have you tested in on?

Comment: This issue occurs when your file selection dialog is over-lapping the div element and then you select the file using double click. The div element triggers mouseup event. I am using chrome browser.

Comment: Hi Samuel, are you able to reproduce the issue now?